# Unexpected character in contract.js React issue

Tags: javascript, deploy, origination

everyone. I generated a smart contract js representation using this command below :

```
completium-cli generate javascript ./contract/mycontract.arl > ./src/contract.js
```

and i get this error :

```
Line 1:  Parsing error: Unexpected character '�'. (1:0)
```

this is my contract.js file :

```
export const mk_int    = v  => {return { "int" : v.toString() }}
export const mk_string = v  => {return { "string" : v }}
export const mk_bytes  = v  => {return { "bytes" : v.toString() }}
export const mk_some   = v  => {return { "prim": "Some", "args": [ v ] }}
export const mk_none   = () => {return { "prim": "None" }}
export const mk_rational = (n, d) => {return {  "prim": "Pair", "args": [ {  "int": n.toString()  }, {  "int": d.toString()  } ] }}

/* Code */

export const code =
  [  {  "prim": "storage",
        "args": [
          {  "prim": "pair",
             "args": [
               {  "prim": "address",
                  "annots": [
                   .
                   .
                   .
                   .
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed it by using this solution : [www.stackoverflow.com/a/51349619](http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/51349619)

Comment: Glad you solved your issue. Please remember to mark the answer as the accepted answer in order to close the question, thanks